# construct case class from collection of parameters

Tags: scala, case-class

Given:

```
case class Thing(a:Int, b:String, c:Double)

val v = Vector(1, "str", 7.3)
```

I want something that will magically create:

```
Thing(1, "str", 7.3)
```

Does such a thing exist (for arbitrary size Things)?

Comment: I wonder if the new 2.10 reflection could handle that. Are you restricted to 2.9.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first time dipping my toes into the 2.10 experimental reflection facilities. So mostly following this outline http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html, I came up with this:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe=>ru}

case class Thing(a: Int, b: String, c: Double)

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val v = Vector(1, "str", 7.3)
    val thing: Thing = Ref.runtimeCtor[Thing](v)
    println(thing) // prints: Thing(1,str,7.3)
  }
}

object Ref {
  def runtimeCtor[T: ru.TypeTag](args: Seq[Any]): T = {
    val typeTag = ru.typeTag[T]
    val runtimeMirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

    val classSymbol = typeTag.tpe.typeSymbol.asClass
    val classMirror = runtimeMirror.reflectClass(classSymbol)

    val constructorSymbol = typeTag.tpe.declaration(ru.nme.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
    val constructorMirrror = classMirror.reflectConstructor(constructorSymbol)
    constructorMirrror(args: _*).asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}
```

Note that when I had the case class inside the main method, this did not compile. I don't know if type tags can only be generated for non-inner case classes.

Comment: Thanks, going to play with this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible to get a working solution with a compile-time error, but this is my solution using matching:

```
case class Thing(a: Int, b: String, c: Double)
def printThing(t: Thing) {
  println(t.toString)
}

implicit def vectToThing(v: Vector[Any]) = v match {
  case (Vector(a: Int, b: String, c: Double)) => new Thing(a, b, c)
}

val v = Vector(1, "str", 7.3) // this is of type Vector[Any]
printThing(v) // prints Thing(1,str,7.3)
printThing(Vector(2.0, 1.0)) // this is actually a MatchError
```

Is there an actual purpose to this "Thing"-conversion or would you rather use Tuple3[Int,String,Double] instead of Vector[Any]?

Comment: I need it to not be tied to the length of the collection. It doesn't need to be a vector but it needs to be of arbitrary length.

Comment: OK - right - but in the end, you will have to construct some case object, right? And this case object would take a specific number of parameters of specific types.
Could you give examples of _how_ you would use your library?

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's not clear what you will use it for. What you call a Thing might actually be a HList or a KList. HList stands for *Heterogeneous Lists* which is an "arbitrary-length tuple".

I am unsure how hard it would be to add an 'unnapply' or 'unapplySeq' method in order for it to behave more like a case class.

I have little experience with them, but a good explanation can be found here: http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/type-level-programming-in-scala/

If this is not what you need it might be a good idea to tell us what you want to achieve.

Comment: It is for a library that will take a case class type parameter to convert things to a case class. Was hoping for a generic solution.

Comment: Could you write down how you would like to call this method? Is it something like `library.construct[CaseClassType]("one" :: 1 :: true :: Nil)`?

Comment: If the constructor arguments do not come as a `Seq[Any]` but as something that looks like a tuple, then you don't have to write your own HList. You can use https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless