# Scala 2.10 reflection: constructor of case class inside a class

Tags: scala, reflection, case-class

I've used the accepted answer of this question to build little helper class to construct case classes from arrays of values:
[construct case class from collection of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785054/construct-case-class-from-collection-of-parameters)

As mentioned in the answer, inner case classes don't work. You get a

```
ScalaReflectionException: class X is an inner class, use reflectClass on an InstanceMirror to obtain its ClassMirror
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use an InstanceMirror as the exception explains. Here's my current REPL-able code (slightly more complex than needed because of the cache).

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._ 

object ReflectUtil {
  private val constructorCache = collection.mutable.HashMap[String, MethodMirror]()

  def constructFromSeq[T: TypeTag](args: Seq[Any]): T = {
    val tag = typeTag[T]
    val strTag = tag.toString
    var constructorMirror = constructorCache.getOrElseUpdate( strTag, {
      val rm = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
      val classSymbol = tag.tpe.typeSymbol.asClass
      val classMirror = rm.reflectClass(classSymbol) // wrap with try/catch?
      val constructorSymbol = tag.tpe.declaration(nme.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
      classMirror.reflectConstructor(constructorSymbol)
    })
    constructorMirror(args: _*).asInstanceOf[T]
  } 
}   

case class X(a:String, b:Int)

class Out { 
  case class Y(a:String, b:Int) 

  def buildY(arr:Array[Any]) = {
    ReflectUtil.constructFromSeq[Y](arr)
  }
}

val arr = Array[Any]("asdf", 1234)
ReflectUtil.constructFromSeq[X](arr) // this works

val inst = new Out
inst.buildY(arr) // this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exception implies is that you need an outer reference to construct an instance of an inner class (e.g. to construct `Y` you need an instance of `Out`). Then you could do `rm.reflect(instanceOfOut).reflectClass...`.

Comment: As I always like to phrase it, instances of inner / nested classes do not stand alone and can only be instantiated in the context of an instance of the enclosing class.

Comment: Any idea how to get an instance of Out from within my constructFromSeq function? Is there a way to get it from T via reflection?

Comment: Probably you could inspect the signature of T's constructor. But what arguments would you pass to it if it doesn't have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that after asking. Hmm. :(